# How can $A^o \cup B^o = S^n$ yet $A\cap B \cong S^{n-1}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How can one construct $A,B \subset S^n$ such that: $A^o \cup B^o = S^n$ yet $A\cap B \cong S^{n-1}$?

When I look at $S^2$ for example, if I take the northern hemisphere to be $A$ and the southern hemisphere to be $B$, both including the equator (denoted $e$), then clearly $A\cap B \cong S^1$, but $A^o \cup B^o = S^2-e$.
If I try to add anything further to either $A$ or $B$, I get a larger intersection - more like a band around the hemisphere - in which case $A\cap B$ is no longer homeomorphic to $S^1$.

What am I missing?

(This question arose from reading Example 2.46 in [Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf).)

Comment: Since $S^n$ and $S^{n-1}$ live in different spaces, you need to ask yourself what does it even mean in the first place.

Comment: @AsafKaragila so you're hinting that it *is* a homeomorphism and not an equality? (otherwise, I do not see what the problem is, since $A\cap B$, if I can view it as *equaling* $S^{n-1}$, lives in $X=S^n$, so that they live in the same space.

Comment: "[C]an view it as". But what is ***the*** definition of $S^n$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks - I think I see it now (?) -- it is not THE $S^{n-1}$ since this one lives in $\mathbb{R}^n$ while $A\cap B$ still lives in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so this must be a homeomorphism and not an equality. Even so, taking the hemispheres as Hatcher suggests (northern and southern hemispheres) leaves out $e$...

Comment: and if I try to increase either one, I get an intersection that looks like a 'band' around the hemisphere, which is not homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: I always found finite dimensions limiting and could never intuitively grasp "geometrical shapes" and such. So I can only help you this far and no further.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Hatcher is not precise with the Example 2.46. He sometimes uses `=` symbol very loosely, in this case we can save his argument by treating `=` as "homotopy equivalent".

You are correct that you need to take both $A$ and $B$ to be a bit wider than just a hemisphere. Hatcher is imprecise here as well. And in such situation the intersection is not homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$. It is a band around the equator. Fortunately this band does deformation retract onto the equator, which is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$. And for calculating homology having a homotopy equivalence is enough.